# Why is Java RunTime has reported a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on Hex.encodeHex() method call?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I had to include some bittorrent java library to my Android project. My workspace: Android Studio 1.0.2 (osx) and jdk8. I've connected its maven-repository (ttorrent:1.4) with Gradle and after starting using main classes and features i've got an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method encodeHex([BZ)[C in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar).
```

I went to library's code and find out that it's using org.apache.commons.codec from where ttorrent is importing encodeHex and calling it. Looks like binaryHex method is gone! Or it never been. But I went to commons.codec's code and **found** binaryHex in its place and with arguments that I was looking for. How come? Why? My Android Studio found it. But java runtime not.

Comment: Did you manipulate the original error message in any way b/c the method signature is slightly unclear? Anyway, assuming [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.java#Hex.encodeHex%28byte%5B%5D%29) is the method missing, I'd check the version of `commons-codec` library deployed up at runtime and/or the version of the class loaded (assuming you somehow ended up with duplicate versions of this class in your classpath).

Comment: No, that is the clear message. How can I check classpath of project in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the decision was more difficult than I thought. Let's start with the fact that I came across an [article](http://blog.goddchen.de/2013/03/apache-commons-codec-android-compatible/) by Dieser Beitrag'a, from which it is clear that not one I had similar problems. The whole thing turned out that within the Android operating system **already** has *some* libraries that have a **higher** priority use, rather than loaded with dependencies along with the application. Among them there and my *org.apache.commons.codec*.

Yes, such things.

To solve the problem in two ways, either you need to pump source code library and using some tool to rename the project (i.e. org.apache.commons.codec to org.apache.commons.codec.android), collected it to a .jar file, include .jar in a project and at code use imports of the necessary classes only "our" library, or just get the required class to your project and do not pull a megabytes of unneeded code. However, I did just that.
Thanks for help!